# In Android Studio, why android.util.ArrayMap.getOrDefault link to kotlin.collections.Map.getOrDefault?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, intellij-idea, lint

I am using android.util.ArrayMap, which implements java.util.map, whose getOrDefault() function requires API level 24.

But I was not aware of these limit until crashes happened on low API devices, no warning showed in Android Studio.

Even when I click getOrDefault() function, I jump to kotlin.collections.Map.getOrDefault()

I am wondering why is this happening?

[image]

I hope this click could lead me to the correct definition of ArrayMap#getOrDefault(), and there is supposed to be a warning when I call this function.

Answer (score 0):

This warning works fine for me, try check your lint settings in: preferences -> editor -> inspections -> Calling new methods on older versions and make sure you have turned it on with some noticeable severity (Error is the best in my opinion).

[image]

With this settings i can see the error in Android Studio, hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: It was already turned on by default, but android.util.arrayMap is recognized as kotlin.collections.Map by AS when I invoke getOrDefault().